# jquery mobile 1.4.2 and dynamic content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am loading dynamic content in jQuery Mobile collapsible set. It works just fine in old jQuery Mobile references, but fails in the latest version of jQuery.

Old references:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

new references

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.css" />
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquerymobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

Old JSFiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/4c565/5/

It works but in above JSFiddle it can not fetch data from external URLs, so it is not fetching but it works flawlessly on my server where the PHP file is kept.

Here is the new JSFiddle: 
         http://jsfiddle.net/4c565/6/

It does not work at all with new jQuery library. Any idea/advice so that it can work in latest library?

Comment: If you read API, you'll know that `expand` is now `collapsibleexpand` http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/4c565/7/

Comment: @Omar THX for ur reply.but still its not retriving data from server.here is my link http://www.way2enjoy.com/touch/w2et/collapse-new4.php

Comment: @Omar working thx.please give this in answer.i will accept

Comment: @Omar thx for ur help. i am trying to load fresh content if user clicked on collapsed content and again click to expand. but not working., i tried this   function(data){
             $("."+info+" ul.check").html(data).listview('refresh');

  });

}).on('collapse', function () {
    $(this).find('.check').find('li').remove();
});

Comment: Update your question with code.